# How can I configure spring mvc/jsp to output xhtml instead of html?

Tags: java, html, xhtml, spring-mvc

I'm starting to experiment with Spring MVC, and noticed that my jsps are served as html files. E.g.

```
<html>
<head>
...

</html>
```

How can I configure Spring MVC to serve xhtml files instead?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
...
</html>
```

**Note** - SpringMVC prefixes my jsp with the `<html>` tag, so I don't have any room to add the doctype before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no quick fix to this one, basically you have to rewrite your jsps to be html compliant and add the appropriate DOCTYPE.

You can use JSPs to produce pretty much any type of text file. JSP itself doesn't care if you are making a CSV, XHTML, Quirks mode HTML, or anything else.

Now if your using JSPX you are a little more limited in that those files have to be valid xml.

Comment: Please see my comment on @nfechner's answer - I don't understand how that works.

Comment: Spring doesn't add that, some where in one of your jsps you will find both the doc type and the html tag.

Answer (score 1):

Change your JSPs. To the server, all HTML is just text.
But beware, that you need to change more than the doctype. You will also have to check the JSPs (and also included files, etc) that they conform to the new standard. e.g. closing tags, lower-case tag and attribute names.

Comment: not true.. this will break .. since the code generated will not be xhtml compliant.

Comment: I'm sorry, but which part is not true? That the server (not the client) does not care about HTML? The question doesn't mention anything about generated code.

Comment: Sorry if the comment is not very clear... What I should have mentioned is "not adequate". Changing the jsp to xhtml is step 1 of how to make spring mvc work with xhtml. Since some of the code macros will now generate non compliant xhtml tags, the code will start breaking, because of validation issue.

Comment: By "change the JSPs" I didn't mean to suggest that simply changing the doctype is enough. I've updated my answer to make that clear.

Comment: But my JSPs don't include the HTML tag itself, and the doctype. These are automatically added by Spring MVC, and I have no control over them. (Well, Spring may not add the doctype, but it adds the html tag, and the doctype should come before that).

Comment: Spring does not add the header. It may seem that way if you look at a page in certain browsers, as they append them to have at least a chance to render your code. Try adding the headers to your JSP and report on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Following is entry in web.xml for web flow , jsf and xhtml display:

```
    <bean id="jpaFlowExecutionListener" class="org.springframework.webflow.persistence.JpaFlowExecutionListener">
            <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
            <constructor-arg ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

<bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener" />

<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
    <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
        <webflow:listener ref="jpaFlowExecutionListener"/>
        <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
    </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
</webflow:flow-executor>

<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="facesFlowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml"/> 
</webflow:flow-registry>

<faces:flow-builder-services id="facesFlowBuilderServices" development="true" />

<faces:resources/>

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
    <property name="defaultHandler">
         <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />
    </property> 
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>

<bean id="faceletsViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView"/>
    <property name ="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"></bean>
```